# Commandlink action gets called before confirmdialog result

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I am new to primefaces .  My question is

I have a p:commandlink in which I have called a confirmation dialog .

But the problem is , the action attribute in the commandlink gets fired even before we click (yes/no) in the confirmation dialog . But the expectation is to trigger the action based on the confirmation dialog . any help is greatly appreciated .

my code snippet :

```
<p:commandLink  value="Lock" disabled="#{bean.disableLock}" action="#{bean.lockdevice("hi" , 0)}" onclick="confirmation1.show();" type="button"  ajax="false" />
<p:confirmDialog message="Are you Sure ?"  header="Confirmation"  showEffect="fade" hideEffect="explode"  widgetVar="confirmation1"  appendTo="@(body)">
<p:commandButton value="Yes" type="button" onclick="confirmation1.hide()"/>
<p:commandButton value="No" type="button" onclick="confirmation1.hide()"/>
</p:confirmDialog>
```

Thanks in Advance .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You either have to put the action on the "Yes"-button:

```
<p:commandLink  value="Lock" disabled="#{bean.disableLock}" onclick="confirmation1.show();" type="button"  ajax="false" />
<p:confirmDialog message="Are you Sure ?"  header="Confirmation"  showEffect="fade" hideEffect="explode"  widgetVar="confirmation1"  appendTo="@(body)">
  <p:commandButton value="Yes" type="button" onclick="confirmation1.hide()" action="#{bean.lockdevice("hi" , 0)}"/>
  <p:commandButton value="No" type="button" onclick="confirmation1.hide()"/>
</p:confirmDialog>
```

or to use `p:confirm`:

```
<p:commandLink  value="Lock" disabled="#{bean.disableLock}" action="#{bean.lockdevice("hi" , 0)}" onclick="confirmation1.show();" type="button"  ajax="false">
  <p:confirm header="Confirmation" message="Are you sure?" icon="ui-icon-alert"/>
</p:commandLink>
```

Have a look at the [showcase](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/confirmDialog.jsf).

Comment: i did as you said (followed second step) ! but now , after the confirm dialog input(say if i give "yes") . the action is not fired .

Comment: thank you , actually it is working !! i removed the onclick attribute , and did set the confirm dialog global attribute to true !! Now its working . thanks